# C# SignalR Client

Tags: c#, multithreading, signalr

I'm using SignalR client version 2.2.0 nuget.

```
this._connection = new HubConnection(this._url);
this._connection.Closed += this.ConnectionOnClosed;
this._connection.Error += this.ConnectionOnError;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 250;
this._client = this._connection.CreateHubProxy(HubName);
this._connection.Start(new WebSocketTransport()).Wait();
```

Then I reuse the client every time (multi-threaded):

`client.Invoke<bool>(nameof(this.AddIfNotExists), key, data, expireAfter)`

```
Parallel.For(
            0,
            50000,
            new ParallelOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10,
            },
            async (i) =>
            {
                var result = await client.ExecuteDistributedAsync(
                    (i % 2).ToString(),
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                    async () =>
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(500);
                            return $"Done: {i} [{(i % 2)}]";
                        });
                Console.WriteLine("--->" + (result ?? "TIMEOUT:" + i));
            });
```

This crashes almost immediately (1st addifnotexist works and then the next 8 it crashes). From what I've read everywhere the IHubProxy is supposed to be thread-safe... 
Any suggestions?

Comment: I dont know this library, but most webclients I know are not threadsafe and only 1 client per user.

Comment: "From what I've read everywhere the IHubProxy is supposed to be thread-safe" - any prooflinks?

Comment: That doesn't make sense imho. I cannot create a new hubproxy after the connection.start is called. That would mean that the websocket is created each time I use the client...  Then I could use a webclient. It's supposed to be faster by keeping the connection open.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client

Search: Thread-safe.

Comment: What is the crash? If it crashes for another reason, all your description above is useless. Show the exception message in all detail.

Comment: This is basically all I got back in the exception:

Connection was disconnected before invocation result was received.=>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to create an objectpool and threads would take it from the pool and put it back when done using. The SignalR client is not threadsafe for sure.